# How to map np.array values?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of the following shape - (363, 640, 4),
with the following values -  [ 67 219 250 255]

e.g:

[Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogvrh.png)

I want to map this array into the same size (363,640) but the values to be an integer 127.

I have tried to use numpy.vectorize without success, it returns None on the all array.

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. please read [mre]. 2. show your code 3. show this on a small array 4. show *exact* expected output

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand the question, so I'm gonna guess you want to create an array, which we'll call B, with the same shape as the array you are showing, which we'll call A.

So I'm assuming you want B to be of the same shape as A, but filled with 127? Correct me if that's not the case, but to do what I'm guessing should be something along the lines:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((363, 640, 4)) # Just to initialize the array to something with your shape 
B = np.full(np.shape(A), 127) # Returns an array of shape A filled with 127
```

Tell me if that is what you expected, if not, please could you detail a bit more the issue?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I want is to map the values [ 67 219 250 255] into 127, so basically if we have an array A filled with [ 67 219 250 255] elements, I want to create a new array B where its values would be 127 (in the same places from A)